# How to install packages using Homebrew in a Conda environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, conda, apple-m1

I'm currently trying to build a conda virtual environment for a project. However some packages are still not possible to install with the pip and conda commands (such as pyqt5 or liblsl for instance), but these are necessary for the project.

I tried to install these packages using the `brew install` command, while being in the virtual environment, but the packages do not appear in the conda virtual environment.

So, do you know if it is possible to install packages with the brew command and include it in the virtual environment ?